# C# Deployment of Shockwave Flash Player

Tags: c#, flash, activex, shockwave

I have made a YouTube player in C# using Shockwave Flash dll. When I am inside visual studio it works but when I deploy my application the flash player turns just white. It doesn't play any videos.

I installed the active X plugin for IE but still doesn't work. I know that my applications needs a active X but I don't know the right version to download. I have check adobe site and it gives me a huge list.

Hope someone could help me.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "https://www.youtube.com/v/TBGkbDhE8wM";
        axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
    }
```

By the way I managed to run my software in windows 8 since Win8 has embedded adobe flash player and it works. On the other hand, I installed Adobe Flash player 19 NPAPI and Adobe Flash Player 20 ActiveX on windows 7 but still my software cant run any youtube videos still. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Please add the relevant code regarding this matter.

Comment: My application is working when i am inside my IDE but when i run it inside the bin folder directly, the player doesn't work anymore but it doesn't throw any exception so i believe code is not the issue, maybe i need a flash player to be able to run my application directly inside the bin folder or maybe i need to register something, what do you think?

Comment: Post the relevant code please by editing the question.

Comment: Post Updated,, basically i just grab a shockwaveflash player and drop it on my form . Then on my form load event i drop the code to play the video. It works, no problem, but when i xCopy deploy my application. it doesn't work on their machine and surprisingly it doesn't work on my development machine too when i run the executable file directly.

Comment: If you think this is enough then good luck. Added relevant tags for you.

Comment: I am sorry I don't, but please edit the question and add your new findings under *EDIT:*